# Pg node connection to db freeze

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a problem with connection to postgress from node pg (VPS debian 10).

In my project I have a file with query helper

/db/index.js

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const config = require('../config');

const pool = new Pool(config.devConfig);

pool.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('connection error', err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log('db connected');
  }
});

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
};
```

And I using this query for all routes like this

```
const db = require('../db');
const errorResult = require('../services/errorsHandling');
const validation = require('../services/validation');

const getAllBrands = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { rows: brands } = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM public.brands`);

    res.render('adminBrand', {
      brands,
      baseUrl: req.baseUrl,
      msgPageName: '-',
      msgWithoutBrands: '-',
      msgAddBrand: '-',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    errorResult(res, error);
  }
};
```

On my local machine everything good. But on VPS it doesn't. On VPS I have some settings like

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

and **pg_hba.conf**

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local    all             postgres                               peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

host    all             all             localhost               trust
```

My git repo https://github.com/truezombie/cartel-screens

I don't see any error after npm run start on my VPS and also 'db connected'
but in my local machine if i try to connect from my local machine to VPS db everything ok and I can see 'db connected'.

Ports 3000, 4000, 5432 opened.

Comment: One thing that called my attention in this code is that you are doing the select in public schema. Only for curiosity can you check if the current database is in public schema? We can see in your query `SELECT * FROM public.brands`

Comment: Yes is it public schema

Answer (score -1):

As your pg_hba.conf looks like not touched.
Look to that lines:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer    
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

This is telling you the database could only be accessed be peer authentication mode.
To do that you should access the database with postgres credentials.

```
$sudo su postgres
```

after that you should be prompted password for your super user in linux. After password with success you should see the your bash prompt label change to:

```
postgres@<yourlinuxinstance>
```

Now you can access postgres database with peer authentication mode.

```
$psql -U postgres
#should login in postgres with success
postgres=#
```

In psql command line you should now create the user and password to access the database.

```
CREATE USER foo WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '-+mysecurepasswordforthisuser+-';
CREATE DATABASE passport;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON passport TO foo;
\q #exit psql shell
$exit #exit from su session with postgres username
```

After that you should must access the pg_hba.conf file and change access method, change `peer` to `md5`

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
```

Restart the database

```
$sudo service postgresql restart
```

After that you can configure the current added user password and database in your connection string.

Now you should access your database from your nodejs code with success.

If you need some clarifications you can [access this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04-pt)

Comment: I added with my hands .env on VPS

Comment: Can you access the database via psql? with proper credentials?

Comment: Yes. I can. Like postgress user and like my user.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I tried it and it doesn't help me.

Comment: after npm run start i haven't any error and also i don't see 'db connected' message

Comment: After all changes could you login with psql?

Comment: Yes. I can. Like my new created user from VPS root.

Comment: root@vps-33784:~/Projects/cartel-screens# psql mxiohhuu_currencies truezombie
Password for user truezombie: 
psql (12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

mxiohhuu_currencies=>